# PHP fatal error: class not found (Composer not installing all classes?)

Tags: php, socket.io, composer-php, require, php-socket

I want to use [phpsocket.io](https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io), but the installation process is very poorly described and I'm stuck at an annoying issue. I installed the package with [Getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/download/) but not all the required classes were installed. I tried to test the basic chat demo provided:

```
use Workerman\Worker;
use PHPSocketIO\SocketIO;

// listen port 2021 for socket.io client
$io = new SocketIO(2021);
$io->on('connection', function($socket)use($io){
  $socket->on('chat message', function($msg)use($io){
    $io->emit('chat message', $msg);
  });
});

Worker::runAll();
```

The `Workerman\Worker` class was installed successfully, but the `PHPSocketIO/SocketIO` class gives me an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPSocketIO\SocketIO' not found in /my/root/directory/public_html/PHPSocketIO/server.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /my/root/directory/public_html/PHPSocketIO/server.php on line 7
```

How am I supposed to access that class? It wasn't installed with Getcomposer and I can't find the class folder anywhere. Also, like I said, the install instructions are very poorly described on the Github page. It says under 'Install':

`composer require workerman/phpsocket.io`

What does this mean? What am I supposed to do with this information? The section under 'Run chat example' is also very vague. I tried to `cd` to `examples/chat` but there's no `server.php` file to run. Is this page outdated, or am I just missing something here? All I know it's not very beginners-friendly, so if someone can give me a push in the right direction of where I'm supposed to get the `PHPSocketIO\SocketIO` class, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line before your code. This set a namespace of third party.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

I recommended use sokect.io of nodejs.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I don't know Javascript, so I can't use Node.js. That's the reason I'm using a PHP alternative.